# Neo4j: hierarchy finding cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find the hierarchy - both upward and downward for the following domain model. As being new to neo4j I am having some hurdle to get the right hierarchy with the cypher query.

Any assistance or sample would be a great help to me...

```
(:Person{id=1})-[HAS_CHILD]->(:Person{id=2})-[HAS_CHILD]->(:Person{id=3})-[HAS_CHILD]->(:Person{id=4})-[HAS_CHILD]->(:Person{id=5})
```

....like that to a very deep level & one person can have multiple children.

I am trying to build some query to find

1. A Person and all his children hierarchy
2. A person and his parent hierarchy
3. Relation ship between two person - if any
4. A Person and all his children hierarchy - up to a specific depth

Answer (score 4):

These should work.

*The `WHERE` clauses are for eliminating subpaths. The answer for #4 cannot use the same `WHERE` clause, so the results will contain subpaths.*

1.

```
MATCH p=(:Person{id:1})-[:HAS_CHILD*]->(c)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:HAS_CHILD]->()
RETURN NODES(p);
```

2.

```
MATCH p=(:Person { id:5 })<-[:HAS_CHILD*]-(ancestor)
WHERE NOT (ancestor)<-[:HAS_CHILD]-()
RETURN NODES(p);
```

3.

```
MATCH p=(p5:Person { id:5 })-[:HAS_CHILD*]-(p1:Person { id:1 })
RETURN NODES(p);
```

4. Using a depth up to 5:

```
MATCH p=(:Person{id:1})-[:HAS_CHILD*1..5]->(c)
RETURN NODES(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your datamodel consisting of `(:Person)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(:Person)` these queries should return the data you are looking for (let's also assume you have a unique `name` property on each `Person` node to facilitate a lookup by name, but you could also use any unique id/property):

**A person and all his children**

We can use a variable length path pattern here to match on patterns containing multiple `HAS_CHILD` relationships.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_CHILD*]->(child:Person)
WHERE p.name = "Bob Loblaw"
RETURN child;
```

**A person and his parent hierarchy**

Very similar to the above query, but we just reverse the relationship direction.

```
MATCH (p:Person)<-[:HAS_CHILD*]-(ancestor:Person)
WHERE p.name = "Bob Loblaw"
RETURN ancestor;
```

**Relationship between two person - if any**

We can use the `shortestPath`  function to find the shortest path between two nodes in the graph. This query will return no rows if no path is found.

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((p:Person {name: "Bob Loblaw"})-[*]-(o:Person {name: "Louise Bluth"}))
RETURN path
```

**A person and their child hierarchy - up to a specific depth**

This query is very similar to the previous "person and all his children query" however we can specify bounds on the variable length path. *Note*: an upper bound should always be specified with variable length paths to avoid very long running queries.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_CHILD*1..5]->(child:Person)
WHERE p.name = "Bob Loblaw"
RETURN child;
```